# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

I have seen numorous questions similar to this, however I still can't seem to resolve the problem, so sorry if this may be a duplicate.

Anyway here is the code:

```
/**
 * 8.This method is used to get no of pending bets.
 */
public function noOfPendingBets($userId){
    $res = array();

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select bet_id from user_bets where user_id=?");
    echo $userId;
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $userId);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($bet_id);
    $num_row=0;
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo "bet_id:".$bet_id."<br>";

    $sumBets=$this->abc($bet_id);
    $num_row = $num_row+$sumBets;



    $stmt->close();
    return $num_row;    

 }

public function abc($bet_id)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select u.user_id from user u inner join bets b on u.user_id=b.creator_id  and b.bet_id=? and b.correct_option is null");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $bet_id);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    echo "no of rows:".$stmt->num_rows;
    return $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("s", $userId); this should be "i"  I beleive, since id is integer not string

Comment: You might need to add the close class so we can see how you are setting the property conn

Comment: tried $stmt->bind_param("i", $userId);...still not working

Comment: is it in your abc function?  Look like you are missing a where clause.

Comment: Post the entire class listing; this code doesn't explain where your db connection is coming from. The problem is likely that your connection is not set correctly, so prepare() is not returning a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

So, `bind_pamam()` has a parent that is a non-object. That should be your `$stmt` variable. So `$stmt` is not an object. Add in this test:

```
if (!is_object($stmt)) die('ERROR: My statement is not an object!');
```

Just after you've made the statement. If you get the error message then you know what the problem is. I cannot explain, from the code you've given, why this does occur, and why it doesn't generate an error sooner.